# How can I go get this Kubernetes package - unknown revision

Tags: go, kubernetes, go-get

How can I go get [this](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kubernetes@v1.26.1/pkg/serviceaccount) kubernetes package.

I have tried the following

```
go get k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/serviceaccount
```

but I get the error

```
go: k8s.io/api@v0.0.0: reading k8s.io/api/go.mod at revision v0.0.0: unknown revision v0.0.0
```

any suggestions on how I get it ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the kubernetes version which you are trying is not available. Please update your go.mod file to use an updated version.

`Require { k8s.io/api v0.22.1}` and try running `‘go get k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/serviceaccount’` again. Please check this official [page](https://go.dev/doc/modules/gomod-ref), and also check this [comment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/issues/1197#issuecomment-863093324).

Comment: That is not what I am looking for. I am looking for `serviceaccount` not `api`

Comment: Try with import "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/serviceaccount"; if you are still facing issues with importing the package then you need to update go.mod file.